# How can I show another Entity linked to the main one on html.twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, entity

I have a problem with showcasing an Entity's property on another one's html.twig that is linked.

Basically, one entity called Cats, one Entity called Appointment relation ManyToOne (one cat can have several appointments but one appointment is linked to one cat only)

Cats entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Appointment::class, mappedBy="cat", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $appointments;

/**
 * @return Collection|Appointment[]
 */
public function getAppointments(): Collection
{
    return $this->appointments;
}

public function addAppointment(Appointment $appointment): self
{
    if (!$this->appointments->contains($appointment)) {
        $this->appointments[] = $appointment;
        $appointment->setCat($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeAppointment(Appointment $appointment): self
{
    if ($this->appointments->removeElement($appointment)) {
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($appointment->getCat() === $this) {
            $appointment->setCat(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Appointment entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Cats::class, inversedBy="appointments", cascade={"persist"} )
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $cat;

public function getCat(): ?Cats
{
    return $this->cat;
}

public function setCat(?Cats $cat): self
{
    $this->cat = $cat;

    return $this;
}
```

And here is what I tried to do in html.twig for appointment_show

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Appointment{% endblock %}
{% block main %}

<h1>Appointment</h1>

{% for cat in appointment.cats %}
    <div>
        <td>{{ appointment.cat_id }}</td>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

So I keep getting for error:

**Neither the property "cats" nor one of the methods "cats()", "getcats()"/"iscats()"/"hascats()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\Appointment".**

Can you help?

Comment: Since `Appointment::$cat` is `ManyToOne`, meaning Many Appointment entities have One Cat entitiy. In your twig `{% for cat in appointment.cats %}` should be `{% set cat = appointment.cat %}` which translates to `Appointment::getCat(): Cat` while `cat.appointments` translates to `Cat::getAppointments(): Collection` (One Cat entity has Many Appointment entities) Also `{{ apointment.cat_id }}` should be `{{ cat.id }}`

Comment: It tried changing it to 

{% set cat = appointment.cat %} 

<div> 

<td>{{ cat.id }}</td> 

</div>

And as a réponse, I have "Variable "appointment" does not exist."

Why do you think?

Comment: Would have needed to see the controller that was rendering the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, I changed my code to the following and it worked:

```
{% for appointment in appointments %}
    {% set cat = appointment.cat %}
        <div>
            {{ cat.id }}
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```